# How to mimic something like "set intersection" and "set union" with Clojure(Script) strings?

Tags: string, clojure, clojurescript, set-theory

Suppose `S` and `T` are strings defined respectively as follows:

```
;; S
A
B
C

;; T
B
C
D
```

Are there analogous clojure(script) operations `string-intersection` and `string-union` (for lack of a better name) that satisfy the following?

```
(string-intersection S T)
;; => 
;; B
;; C
```

and

```
(string-union S T)
;; => 
;; A
;; B
;; C
;; D
```

As you can see, `string-intersection` would eliminate (on a line-by-line basis) non-matching lines (leaving only the lines that match), while `string-union` has the effect of combining lines and ignoring duplicates.

**NOTE:** I'm using clojurescript, but I imagine the answer would generalize to clojure as well.

Comment: You should be able to implement both functoins in most languages by splitting both strings in lines, order them (if they are unordered) and merge. The merge strategy is just different for the two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems you would like to treat your strings as a set of lines and calculate set intersection and union.

For working with sets, you can use `clojure.set` namespace.

First convert your strings into a set of lines:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str]
         '[clojure.set :as set])

(def s "A\nB\nC")
(def t "B\nC\nD")

(def s-set (into #{} (str/split-lines s)))
(def t-set (into #{} (str/split-lines t)))
```

Then you can calculate your union and intersection:

```
(def s-t-union (set/union s-set t-set))
;; => #{"C" "B" "A" "D"}

(def s-t-intersection (set/intersection s-set t-set))
;; => #{"C" "B"}
```

And sort it:

```
(def s-t-union-sorted (sort s-t-union))
;; => ("A" "B" "C" "D")

(def s-t-intersection-sorted (sort s-t-intersection))
;; => ("B" "C")
```

You can also convert it back to String of lines:

```
(str/join "\n" s-t-union-sorted)
;; => "A\nB\nC\D"

(str/join "\n" s-t-intersection-sorted)
;; => "B\nC"
```